# Raspberry Pi 3 not lirc not running/working

Tags: lirc

Im trying to get my Pi to take input from an IR remote using lirc. But it is not working. Ive tried a few different tutorials [like this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ymFO0oFyXA4) that basically did the same thing.

[image]

One problem here is the the Pi couldnt find /etc/init.d/lirc, so i could not stop it. The test (mode2 -d /dev/lirc0) also fails, it does not tell me anything.

Under /boot/config.txt I have

```
dtoverlay=lirc-rpi,gpio_in_pin=17
```

hardware.conf is

```
# /etc/lirc/hardware.conf
#
# Arguments which will be used when launching lircd
LIRCD_ARGS="--uinput"

# Don't start lircmd even if there seems to be a good config file
# START_LIRCMD=false

# Don't start irexec, even if a good config file seems to exist.
# START_IREXEC=false

# Try to load appropriate kernel modules
LOAD_MODULES=true

# Run "lircd --driver=help" for a list of supported drivers.
DRIVER="default"
# usually /dev/lirc0 is the correct setting for systems using udev
DEVICE="/dev/lirc0"
```

Also the wiring is like this
[image]

Comment: Check out some info here that might help:
https://github.com/SteveAmor/cheerlights/blob/master/candle/README.md

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update 2019-06-14:**
Please note that the [infrared device has recently changed from `lirc-rpi` to
`gpio-ir`](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=236240). As confirmed by [@Pascal in his comment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/81876/raspberry-pi-3-not-lirc-not-running-working/81885?noredirect=1#comment172805_81885) the setup also works with the new device name.

---

Here is how I got it to work. First of all: I use the latest [Raspbian Stretch Lite 2018-03-13](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/). With this version there is no `/etc/lirc/hardware.conf` anymore if you install `lirc`. You should also use up to date versions.

In `/boot/config.txt` enable the infrared device. `GPIO 17 out` and `GPIO 18 in` are default and you can omit their settings. I have added them if you use other pins. You can find the settings in `/boot/overlays/README`.

```
# Uncomment this to enable the gpio-ir module
dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_out_pin=17,gpio_in_pin=18,gpio_in_pull=up

# Or still using the old version uncomment this to enable the lirc-rpi module
dtoverlay=lirc-rpi,gpio_out_pin=17,gpio_in_pin=18,gpio_in_pull=up
```

Install `lirc`:

```
rpi3 ~$ sudo apt update
rpi3 ~$ sudo apt install lirc
```

Edit `/etc/lirc/lirc_options.conf` and change this settings to:

```
driver = default
device = /dev/lirc0
```

Now

```
rpi3 ~$ sudo systemctl reboot
```

After login you should have a `lirc0` device and see something like:

```
rpi3 ~$ ls -l /dev/lirc0
crw-rw---- 1 root video 244, 0 2018-01-28 16:58 /dev/lirc0
rpi3 ~$ lsmod | grep lirc
lirc_rpi                9032  3
lirc_dev               10583  1 lirc_rpi
rc_core                24377  1 lirc_dev
```

Check services with:

```
rpi3 ~$ systemctl status lircd.service
rpi3 ~$ systemctl status lircd.socket
```

Now you can test if you get signals. Start `mode2` and push some buttons on your remote control. `mode2` should show you very low level info in `space` and `pulse`:

```
rpi3 ~$ sudo systemctl stop lircd.service
rpi3 ~$ sudo systemctl stop lircd socket
rpi3 ~$ sudo mode2 --driver default --device /dev/lirc0
```

If everything is OK to this, we can start `lirc` again:

```
rpi3 ~$ sudo systemctl start lircd socket
rpi3 ~$ sudo systemctl start lircd.service
```

Now we need a configuration file that maps the lirc pulses to the buttons of your remote control. On the internet there is a [database with many config files for remote controls](http://lirc-remotes.sourceforge.net/remotes-table.html). the config file for my remote control I have found there. If you cannot find yours you have to training your remote control by yourself with:

```
rpi3 ~$ sudo irrecord -n -d /dev/lirc0 ~/lircd.conf
```

That's your exercise ;-) Haven't tested it. If you have your config file move it to
`/etc/lirc/lircd.conf.d/`
and restart `lirc` to load this file:

```
rpi3 ~$ sudo systemctl restart lircd
```

Now we can look if we get the pushed buttons. Start `irw` and push buttons on your remote control. You should get something like:

```
rpi3 ~$ irw
0000000000002422 00 KEY_VOLUMEUP Sony_RMT-CS33AD
0000000000002422 01 KEY_VOLUMEUP Sony_RMT-CS33AD
0000000000002422 02 KEY_VOLUMEUP Sony_RMT-CS33AD
0000000000006422 00 KEY_VOLUMEDOWN Sony_RMT-CS33AD
0000000000006422 01 KEY_VOLUMEDOWN Sony_RMT-CS33AD
0000000000006422 02 KEY_VOLUMEDOWN Sony_RMT-CS33AD
```

Last step is to give these events actions, e.g. start a program. For this we use the program `irexec`. This needs its config file `~/.config/lircrc` with entries like this (simple example):

```
begin
prog = irexec
button = KEY_VOLUMEUP
config = echo "Volume-Up"
end
begin
prog = irexec
button = KEY_VOLUMEDOWN
config = echo "Volume-Down"
end
```

For any button add a new block `begin ... end`. The button name is exact the name you get with `irw`. As action (line `config =`) I do a simple `echo` so you can see on the console what button was pressed. Here you can call any other program, e.g. system programs, bash scripts, python programs, what you want. Look at `man irexec`.

[Thanks to manthony121](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=205490) in his last comment.

Have fun :-)

Comment: I purchased this [IR Expansion Board](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B076BDR34K) for Raspberry Pi 3, with these [setup instructions](http://www.raspberrypiwiki.com/index.php/Raspberry_Pi_IR_Control_Expansion_Board). My RPi3 is running the latest version of Raspbian OS (Stretch April 2019). Your instructions are slightly different, but the instructions on the product wiki also calls out a required step 2 if Raspbian older than Feb 2019. I don't see a `/dev/lirc0` device.

Comment: For the newest kernel `dtoverlay=lirc-rpi,gpio_out_pin=17,gpio_in_pin=18,gpio_in_pull=up` should be `dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_out_pin=17,gpio_in_pin=18,gpio_in_pull=up` otherwise the guide worked perfectly

Comment: @Pascal Thanks for the feedback. I have updated the answer.