# LIRC Doesn't detect remotes

Tags: linux, debian, lirc, aptitude

I've got some data that I want to send through IR, and I've got one remote working, with [this](https://pastebin.com/ygX6BMKh) config file. However, this is the only config file that LIRC recognizes. I've been putting all files into `/etc/lirc/lirc.conf.d/`.

[This](https://pastebin.com/VGKfx7TP) file, formatted the same way, is not recognised by LIRC, nor is [this](https://pastebin.com/n8r94ZuD) example file I downloaded from LIRC.

I've tried adding the file directly to lirc.conf, restarting lirc.d (many times, and both through `sudo service lircd restart` and `sudo /etc/init.d/lirc.d restart`, I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling LIRC, among other things. I've also tried changing the names between the files. I just can't find the difference that's causing this no-detect problem.

Comment: I have worked on it for some month. Maybe you can find some hints? [Raspberry Pi 3 not lirc not running/working](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/81885/79866)