# Read TV remote IR codes for building a RPi3-powered remote

Tags: pi-3, lirc

I am trying to figure out how to read IR codes of a TV remote, so I can build my own web-based remote using a Raspberry Pi 3 with IR receiver and IR transmitter. I see a ton of articles online but could not find an article that articulates a DIY tutorial on just this part.

Ultimately, I want to map all the buttons on a TV remote, and then build a web based interface used to transmit the user selected IR codes to control a TV.

I have a RPi3 (second gen) kit with some basic accessories like breadboard, resistors, and jumper wires. IR receiver and transmitter components are confusing to choose, depending on which article I am reading.

Comment: This question is pretty broad for this site.  Questions should typically be more focused on specific problems that you've encountered with examples of what you've tried.

Comment: http://www.lirc.org/

Comment: most of the work of reading the signal has already been done .... what is the TV manufacturer and model?

Comment: @jsotola Sony XBR55X930E

Comment: here is some info about the sony IR protocol https://www.sbprojects.net/knowledge/ir/sirc.php ....... http://www.righto.com/2010/03/understanding-sony-ir-remote-codes-lirc.html

Comment: it looks like sony TVs can be controlled by a wifi remote .... it should be easier to implementt that IR remote .... http://docs.esupport.sony.com/imanual/NA/EN/hx750/mediaremote.html

Answer (score 2):

While answers which are mostly links are discouraged, IR is NOT simple enough to explain in a few paragraphs.

You seem well informed already acknowledging that each button has its own code. That is a little bit over simplified (depending on the "codes" being used), but you at least have a good grasp of it and what you want to do.

The Pi has a great IR package called LIRC (think Linux Infrared Remote Control) which has a lot of documentation.

This link is pretty much exactly what you are looking for and it sounds like you have already looked at quite a few ideas.

This was built using a Pi Zero, just a stripped down Pi. Using LIRC really makes it slick!

www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Zero-Universal-Remote/.

Comment: I have the latest version of Raspbian Stretch April 2019 work kernel 4.19. `lirc-pi` seems to be replaced by `gpio-ir`. Also irrecord is unable to detect my Sony remote's IR signals, even though mode2 is detecting the pulses and spaces just fine. I read somewhere that Sony remotes use 40 khz instead of 38 khz. Is this behind the issues I am running into?

Comment: Any 36 khz receiver will receive 38 and 40 khz. And any 38 khz will receive 36 and 40 khz. Their frequency "selection" is quite broad. In the equipment I worked with our 38 khz receivers worked fine with 25 khz IR remotes. I have read that LIRC was either dropped or replaced. I have not worked with it for a while...

Answer (score 1):

You can use **lirc** to achieve what you want. When you have installed it you can use its diagnose tool `mode2` to get low level information about the signals that are received from the remote control.

Then you need a configuration file that maps the lirc pulses to the buttons of your remote control. On the internet there is a [database with many config files for remote controls](http://lirc-remotes.sourceforge.net/remotes-table.html). If you cannot find yours you have to training your remote control by yourself with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo irrecord -n -d /dev/lirc0 ~/lircd.conf
```

Next step is to use `irw` to check which button of your remote control has what action (volume up/down etc.).

Finally you can use `irexec` to map a script to each button on the remote control that is executed when the button is pressed. Within this script you can send commands through a web based interface to control a TV.

For details how to do all this using a Raspberry Pi you can look at [Raspberry Pi 3 lirc running/working](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/81885/79866).

---

If you are looking for an alternative to **lirc** you can use direct kernel support with **gpio-ir**. Look at `/boot/overlay/README`. There you will find:

```
Name:   gpio-ir
Info:   Use GPIO pin as rc-core style infrared receiver input. The rc-core-
        based gpio_ir_recv driver maps received keys directly to a
        /dev/input/event* device, all decoding is done by the kernel - LIRC is
        not required! The key mapping and other decoding parameters can be
        configured by "ir-keytable" tool.
Load:   dtoverlay=gpio-ir,<param>=<val>
Params: gpio_pin                Input pin number. Default is 18.

        gpio_pull               Desired pull-up/down state (off, down, up)
                                Default is "up".

        rc-map-name             Default rc keymap (can also be changed by
                                ir-keytable), defaults to "rc-rc6-mce"


Name:   gpio-ir-tx
Info:   Use GPIO pin as bit-banged infrared transmitter output.
        This is an alternative to "pwm-ir-tx". gpio-ir-tx doesn't require
        a PWM so it can be used together with onboard analog audio.
Load:   dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,<param>=<val>
Params: gpio_pin                Output GPIO (default 18)

        invert                  "1" = invert the output (make it active-low).
                                Default is "0" (active-high).
```

Comment: I want to train my remote, this feels like a good start. Is the wiring in the article you linked something that you followed or vouch for?

Comment: @WebUser The wiring at [Raspberry Pi 3 not lirc not running/working](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/81876/79866) isn't mine. It's shown by the asker. I cannot say anything about it. I used a soldered IR receiver on a D/A audio HAT.

Comment: What are  the alternative for LIRC on the Raspberry Pi? Glad to hear that different khz can be handled by the 38khz receiver.

Comment: @WebUser I have updated my answer at the end.