# LIRC could not connect to socket

Tags: python, sockets, lirc

After installing on Raspberry lirc-0.10.1 according to this instruction ([Setup IR Remote Control Using LIRC for the Raspberry PI (RPi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57437261/setup-ir-remote-control-using-lirc-for-the-raspberry-pi-rpi)), when you try to send data from any config file, the `irsend -d /dev/lirc0 SEND_ONCE devinput-32 KEY_POWER` command displays a message:

```
do_connect: could not connect to socket
connect: Connection refused
Cannot open socket /dev/lirc0: Connection refused
```

Devices /dev/lirc0 and /dev/lirc1 work (checked with `ir-ctl`). The transfer runs `/dev/lirc0`. Socket `/var/run/lirc/lircd` is writable and readable by everyone. 
Why can't irsend work?

Comment: I haven't followed the link you have given, tldr; but you may compare it with the answer to this question [Raspberry Pi 3 not lirc not running/working](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/81885/79866).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thou shalt not use /dev/lirc0 as an argument to irsend. irsend sends data to the lircd daemon, and the lircd daemon send (raw) data to /dev/lirc0.

So, irsend should send data to the socket where lircd listens, by default /var/run/lirc/lircd.

Answer (score 1):

Leamas, thank you very much! Dealt with the socket and the device. Confused by the old instructions for using lirc. I downloaded a good config file and ran irsend without specifying a socket and everything worked

```
irsend SEND_ONCE PHILIPS_15PF4121 KEY_POWER
```