# Getting an error while trying to set up LIRC

Tags: pi-3, lirc

I'm a new Raspberry Pi 3 user and barely understand anything, I'm only familiar with Windows based platforms so I'm a little lost. I'm currently following a tutorial on how to set up lirc_rpi to send and receive IR signals, I'm very aware that I'm getting involved with deprecated software here but the work around is very confusing to me. I'm not looking for efficiency, I'm looking for a working program. Anyways, while trying to run the command:

```
$sudo modprobe lirc_rpi
```

I get the error:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module lirc_rpi not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.32-v7+
```

and don't understand what this means or how to fix it. Hoping somebody here can help. If what I'm trying to do truly doesn't work anymore I may need help figuring out an alternative.

Comment: I think the tutorial you're following may be out of date? I can't seem to find anything recent that suggests running `modprobe lirc_rpi`. Have you looked at https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=243583 or https://devkimchi.com/2020/08/12/turning-raspberry-pi-into-remote-controller/ ? 

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/81876/raspberry-pi-3-not-lirc-not-running-working also looks relevant.

Comment: See [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works.
and [How do I ask a good question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)